# Not getting millisecond data when executing SProc via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Im having some issues getting all the data from my sql server database. Below is one of the DateTime values i have stored in my database:

```
2012-12-31 21:39:08.8940
```

Unfortunately, when i run the same SProc via entity framework, i get the following instead:

```
2012-12-31 21:39:08
```

Is there anyway to correct this so all the data is being returned?

The SProc code is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataRetrieval]
    @StartDateTime      DateTime2(4)        ='2012-12-31 21:59:08.2050',
    @EndDateTime        DateTime2(4)        ='2012-12-31 21:59:08.2050',
    @Pair               nchar(6)            ='EurUsd'
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

SELECT Pair,DateTime,Ask,Bid,AskVolume,BidVolume
FROM 
    dbo.ForexData
WHERE
    PAIR = @Pair
    AND ( DateTime = @StartDateTime  
               OR DateTime >= @StartDateTime )
    AND ( DateTime = @EndDateTime
           OR DateTime < @EndDateTime )
ORDER BY
    DateTime
END
GO
```

Comment: What type is the column in the database?

Comment: DateTime2(4) and nulls arent allowed.

Comment: And the type used in the SProc?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth DateTime in the c# code. SProc code has been added to the original question.

Comment: Is there a chance that in your C# code the millisecond data is there and it's just not being shown in the current format? i.e, Your format only includes HH:MM:SS?

Comment: @Kevin yeah im assuming its something to do with how the Entity framework is storing the data. When i select the ComplexType which it made to hold the data, the sub-second data is missing at that point.

Comment: @HansRudel and the DateTime column in dbo.ForexData is also a DateTime2?

Comment: @Kevin yes. Daniel asked that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in your *.edmx, under the ComplexType section, the Precision property is filled correctly